# Как удалить класс при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть 2 скрипта.

Первый скрипт: при нажатии на кнопку "Клик", для мобильного меню добавляется класс `menu-mobile_active`.

Второй скрипт: при нажатии на любую область, помимо самого мобильное меню, у мобильного меню удаляется класс `menu-mobile_active`.

Но при нажатии на кнопку "Клик", класс m`menu-mobile_active` у мобильного меню не удаляется.

Ссылка на код: https://jsfiddle.net/ygcjhbqf/6/

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
  $('.menu-mobile').toggleClass('menu-mobile_active');
});

// Скрытие меню при клике на область помимо самого меню
$(document).mouseup(function(e) { // событие клика по веб-документ
  var div = $(".menu-mobile"); // тут указываем class элемента
  if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
    &&
    div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
    $(".menu-mobile").removeClass('menu-mobile_active');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-mobile {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  opacity: .3;
}

.menu-mobile_active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-mobile">Мобильное меню</div>
<button class="menu-toggle">Клик</button>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```

Как сделать так, чтобы и при нажатии на кнопку "Клик", у мобильного меню удалялся класс `menu-mobile_active`?

Comment: Работает же ваш код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.menu-toggle').click(function() {
console.log('.menu-toggle');
  $('.menu-mobile').toggleClass('menu-mobile_active');
});

// Скрытие меню при клике на область помимо самого меню
$(document).mouseup(function(e) { // событие клика по веб-документ
console.log('document');
  var div = $(".menu-mobile"); // тут указываем class элемента
  var toggle = $('.menu-toggle');
  if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
    &&
    !toggle.is(e.target)
    &&
    div.has(e.target).length === 0) { // и не по его дочерним элементам
    $(".menu-mobile").removeClass('menu-mobile_active');
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-mobile {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  opacity: .3;
}

.menu-mobile_active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-mobile">Мобильное меню</div>
<button class="menu-toggle">Клик</button>https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
```